# Accessing parent context within a backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, xmlhttprequest

I have an xhr setRequestHeader that runs a method on a model in Backbone.js. When trying to refer to the model's context using 'this' it refers to the xhr request instead of the model.

Within initialize I created a variable called self that refers to this but it returns undefined in the sendAuth method.

I have tried a number of ways to refer to Authentication from within sendAuth without luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var Authentication = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.token = Distillery.config.defaultToken;
    },
    setToken: function(token) {
        self.token = token;
    },
    resetToken: function() {
        self.token = Distillery.config.defaultToken;
    },
    sendAuth: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'token ' +self.token);
    }
});

var authentication = new Authentication;

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: authentication.sendAuth
});
```

Comment: defining self as this is only defining self in your initialize method - also, is it just a typo that there's no closing paren on your function invocation in sendAuth? - you should be able to use this to refer to the Model object in the setRequestHeader parameter, provided you've defined this.token somewhere appropriate, such as the initialize method

Comment: Yeah it was just a typo.

That's interesting becuse when I refer to self in any of the other methods it refers to the parent model. When I refer to this or self inside sendAuth I get the xhr request properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to define 'self' here (and in your code, 'self' is only good within the initialize method).

So, change your model to something like this:

```
var Authentication = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'sendAuth');
    this.resetToken();
  },
  setToken: function(token) {
    this.token = token;
  },
  resetToken: function() {
    this.token = Distillery.config.defaultToken;
  },
  sendAuth: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'token ' + this.token);
  }
});
```

I believe when you pass the method to ajaxSetup, the caller of the method is no longer 'authentication' but the $.ajax object, that's why this.token is undefined. using _.bindAll in initialize ensures when sendAuth is called, 'this' in sendAuth always refers to the backbone object.